# How can you create such a shape using css?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

[image: shape-css?]

How to create a circle background and crop it in div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple clip-path can do it:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  background:lightblue;
  clip-path:circle(farthest-side);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or a radial-gradient

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  background:radial-gradient(circle farthest-side,lightblue 98%,#0000);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    width: 320px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.circle {
    background-color: #aad2dd;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```